# Sort In Realm with the length of string

Tags: java, android, sql, database, realm

in realm documentation, it is written to

```
result = result.sort("name", Sort.DESCENDING);
```

simple sort but i want to sort by shortest name First

normally in MySql we have

```
order by CHAR_LENGTH(Field)
```

is there any method like this in realm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but you could easily have a redefined setter since 0.88.0 where you do the following:

```
public class Word extends RealmObject {
    private String name;

    @Index
    @Required
    private long nameLength;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.nameLength = name == null ? 0 : name.length();
    }
}
```

And you can specify a migration that would create this for pre-existing elements

```
public class Migration implements RealmMigration {
    @Override
    public void migrate(final DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
        RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();
        if(oldVersion == 0) {
            RealmObjectSchema wordSchema = schema.get("Word");
            wordSchema.addField("nameLength", long.class, FieldAttribute.INDEXED, FieldAttribute.REQUIRED)
                      .transform(new RealmObjectSchema.Function() {
                          @Override
                          public void apply(DynamicRealmObject obj) {
                              obj.set("nameLength", obj.getString("name").length());
                          }
                      });
            oldVersion++;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void equals(Object object) {
        return object != null && object instanceof Migration;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Migration.class.hashCode();
    }
}

RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
                                             .schemaVersion(1)
                                             .migration(new Migration())
                                             .build();
```

Then you can easily do

```
 realm.where(Word.class).findAllSorted(WordFields.NAME_LENGTH, Sort.ASCENDING, 
                                       WordFields.NAME, Sort.ASCENDING);
```

Comment: this will run once after installation so as to create new field?, also this will take long time to run for 150000 objects?

Comment: well you **can** also add this field into your asset file as well and then you won't have to specify the migration

Comment: better would be i recreate database with length of `name`  field